# In what sense can Newton's second law be expressed or treated as a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've seen Newton's second law cited as an example of a differential equation.  I find this confusing; here's my best attempt to figure it out.  (1) We can treat force as a function with the parameters $t$ (for time) and $v$ (for velocity); perhaps the idea is that we are starting with data for the velocity of a moving body at particular times.  (2) We can write Newton's second law as $F(t,v)=m\frac{dv}{dt}$.  (3) To conform with the differential equation conventions I've seen, we could rearrange this expression to $\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{1}{m}F(t,v)$.  (4) We can treat this expression as a differential equation, with $m$ as a constant parameter, and $F(t,v)$ as an unknown function in $v$ and $t$.

I'm just looking for a basic conceptual grasp.  Any thoughts or comments would be very welcome.

Comment: It's more clear in specific examples, such as a spring-mass system. The equation $F = ma$ leads to a differential equation, or a system of differential equations, that describes a spring-mass system. It works the same way for many other physical systems.

Comment: In the original, Newton more or less says that force is the change in motion, and his description of motion implies that it is what we would today call momentum. That is, we have $F = \frac{dp}{dt}$, where $p = mv$. That's just my reading; maybe some historians of science can chime in. ¶ I wouldn't focus so much on the *form* of the differential equation; at its heart, a differential equation just relates the way some values change with respect to others (and the way those others change, too).

Comment: Usually the force is also a function of position.

Comment: Newton's equation reads  $m\ddot{x}(t)=F(t,x(t),\dot{x}(t))$ which is a second order ODE (in general, nonlinear) for $x(t)$. This assumes that you are already given the Force function $F$, as well as the initial position $x(0)$ and initial velocity $\dot{x}(0)$, and your job is to find the position $x$. This may not always be the case though (like the two body problem being the simplest example).